# SetVariable Macro: myvar Value: DatePart("Week", myDateVar) - "action has an invalid value"

Tags: ms-access, web-applications

I'm experimenting with a Webapp database. I'm trying to set an AfterUpdate event for a field using SetVariable. When I try to use Datepart("ww", myDateVar) or DatePart("week", myDateVar) Access reports "The SetVariable macro action has an invalid value for the 'Value' argument."

Is there any way to make this work and how would I go about it?

I have tried Macros, Data Macros, AfterUpdate and On Click.

myDateVar is a date field formatted to display Short Date.

myvar is a Number

Comment: Resolved. I wasn't using the correct syntax, but it certainly is not clear in Microsoft documentation. Just had to remove the quotes.

    DatePart(Week, myDateVar)

Answer (score 0):

Resolved. I wasn't using the correct syntax, but it certainly is not clear in Microsoft documentation. Just had to remove the quotes.

```
DatePart(Week, myDateVar)
```